# Positioning of nivo slider

Tags: css, positioning, nivo-slider

I have changed the size of the Nivo slider and caption on [My Site](http://www.popglitch.com) and now the image and slider are off center and hard left. I would like it to be centered with the navigation bar above it. Can someone assist me with this?

Currently I have the following `CSS` for the slider, image and caption properties:

```
.nivoSlider {
  position:absolute;
  width:850px; 
  height:400px;  
  overflow:hidden;
}
.nivoSlider img {
  position:relative; 
  width:850px; 
  height:400px; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  top:0px; 
  display:none;
}
.nivoSlider a {
  border:0; 
  display:block;
}
.nivo-caption {
  position:absolute;  
  bottom:0; 
  background:#09dcc7; 
  padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; 
  z-index:8; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to have it centered, you can use `margin: 0 auto;` on the slider wrapper:

**CSS**

```
#slider-wrapper-full {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;      /* Add this line */
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 850px;
}
```

Comment: One line, 15 chars, nothing more. Life is beautiful.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I wasn't sure if I needed to adjust padding or hard left and right margins or what.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying a different less elegant approach while the answer came.

In the file style.css, do a search for `#slider-wrapper-full` and replace

```
"padding-top:10px;"
```

with

```
"padding: 10px 0px 0px 75px;"
```

However, as @Zuul indicate is much better to add the line `margin: 0 auto;` It will keep other changes you make to your nivo slider size centered.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes the centering approach works well since it will remain centered when I edit the size of the slider.